# Which cryptographic hash function does Ethereum use?

Tags: cryptography, sha3, hash-algorithm, keccak

Many sources refer to the use of the "SHA3" cryptographic hash function within Ethereum, but the Ethereum project began before the SHA3 standard was finalised, and there was some [confusion/controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#NIST_announcement_controversy) around the final parameters selected for the standard.  **Which function specifically did Ethereum actually end up with?**  Is it the same as the actual SHA3 standard, or one of the variants within the standard?  Or is it a parameterisation of [Keccak](http://keccak.noekeon.org/) that doesn't match any of the variants?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Ethereum uses [KECCAK-256](http://keccak.noekeon.org/). It should be noted that it does not follow 
the [FIPS-202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) based standard (a.k.a SHA-3), which was finalized in August 2015.

According to [this](https://github.com/phusion/digest-sha3-ruby/issues/5), NIST changed the padding to `SHA3-256(M) = KECCAK [512] (M || 01, 256).`
This was different from the padding proposed by the Keccak team in [The Keccak SHA-3 submission version 3 (final, winning version)](https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-submission-3.pdf).  The difference is the additional '01' bits appended to the message.  People are now calling the "submitted version 3" SHA-3 Keccak hashing "Keccak" and the finalized NIST SHA-3 standard "SHA-3".

Using [this online generator](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) and the [Solidity Online Compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#gist=f50128d63b5188490fa2), I tested the difference between Keccak-256 and SHA3-256. I hashed the word **testing** using Ethereum and the 2 SHA3 hashing algorithms:

[Ethereum SHA3 function in Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#gist=f50128d63b5188490fa2) = `5f16f4c7f149ac4f9510d9cf8cf384038ad348b3bcdc01915f95de12df9d1b02`

[Keccak-256](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) = `5f16f4c7f149ac4f9510d9cf8cf384038ad348b3bcdc01915f95de12df9d1b02`

[SHA3-256 (NIST Standard)](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_256.html) = `7f5979fb78f082e8b1c676635db8795c4ac6faba03525fb708cb5fd68fd40c5e`

Comment: For clarity's sake I think we should call it "Keccak-256" rather than anything that explicitly says "SHA3" in it.

Comment: You are not alone. See [this EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/59).

Comment: lol, yup familiar with that one.  But I actually meant here in the answer, so that we don't confuse readers.

Comment: Good idea @Jeff. I changed the wording.

Comment: Oh, and excellent answer by the way.  Everyone reading this, please upvote this answer.  It is an ideal example of the kind of answers we'd like to have on this site!!

Comment: [Solidity 0.4.3 has introduced `keccak256`](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#043-2016-10-25), an alias which can safely be used as a replacement for `sha3`.

Comment: How do you pronounce "keccak?"

Comment: @MattSayar [kɛtʃak], like “ketchak”, as seen here: https://www.quora.com/Cryptography-How-should-you-pronounce-Keccak

Comment: The link to keccak-256 in your first line is broken. It redirects to a news archive. Do you have an updated link to the algorithm?

Answer (score 23):

To make it clearer that Ethereum uses [KECCAK-256](http://keccak.noekeon.org) instead of the NIST standardized SHA-3 hash function, [**Solidity 0.4.3 has introduced `keccak256`**](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#043-2016-10-25).  (It is an alias to `sha3`, meaning that `keccak256` produces identical results to `sha3`, but with the intent to avoid [confusion](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce), especially for developers new to Ethereum.)  It's recommended that new code use `keccak256` instead of `sha3`.

Answer (score 1):

Useful info: since late November 2023 (openssl 3.2 release date), openssl supports keccak256 natively.
Linux bash (word **testing**):

```
$ echo -n "testing" | openssl dgst -keccak-256
KECCAK-256(stdin)= 5f16f4c7f149ac4f9510d9cf8cf384038ad348b3bcdc01915f95de12df9d1b02
```

Windows command line (word **testing**):

```
echo|set /p="testing"| openssl.exe dgst -keccak-256
KECCAK-256(stdin)= 5f16f4c7f149ac4f9510d9cf8cf384038ad348b3bcdc01915f95de12df9d1b02
```

Aforementioned http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html with  word **testing**

[Keccak-256](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) = `5f16f4c7f149ac4f9510d9cf8cf384038ad348b3bcdc01915f95de12df9d1b02`