# Are there any plans to switch Ethereum's primary hash algorithm from Keccak-256 to SHA3?

Tags: proof-of-work, cryptography, keccak, sha3, hash-algorithm

The Ethereum project was started before the [SHA3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) standard was finalised, and [currently uses an earlier version of Keccak-256](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550/which-cryptographic-hash-function-does-ethereum-use) which does not precisely match the [FIPS-202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) standard for SHA.  Are there any plans to switch Ethereum's algorithm over to the standard now that it has been published?

Answer (score 4):

SHA3 is just a name and the underlying cryptographic algorithms are elected by an international commitee.

There is no reason why Ethereum should change such a fundamental thing like the basic hash function. This puts the network consensus in danger and would mean a huge effort in upgrading all software and broadcasting the information to all members of the broad ethereum community and network.

Keccak-256 is just fine.

One thing could be done though, in future implementations should the name `sha3` of hashing functions be dropped in favour of `keccak`.

Comment: The primary issue is not the name or security but the software development confusion.  If developers working on the platform are unable to use standard software libraries (which will probably just implement the FIPS-202 standard), instead having to use Ethereum-specific libraries, it creates an unnecessary hurdle.  That's not to say that the algorithm *should* change, just that if Ethereum had been created *after* the standard was published, complying with it would have been strictly better than just using keccak-256.

Comment: [Solidity 0.4.3 has introduced `keccak256`](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#043-2016-10-25), an alias which can safely be used as a replacement for `sha3`.