# Why aren't Solidity sha3 hashes not matching what other sha3 libraries produce?

Tags: solidity, cryptography, keccak, sha3, web3js

Solidity has a function named `sha3` and I tested it with an empty string input.  It is not matching what other sha3 libraries produce.  I see  contracts written by others using the same `sha3` function in Solidity, and their hashes also do not match.  The same goes for Javascript `web3.sha3` hashes.  Why?

Comment: Since you are self answering this; could you give some code samples showing the difference in output and in the answer how to configure such a sha3 library for Keccak-256 compatibility?

Comment: added samples to answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which cryptographic hash function does Ethereum use?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550/which-cryptographic-hash-function-does-ethereum-use)

Comment: People coming from a search engine are going to use different terms.  This is likely to be the type of problem/question people are going to ask.

Comment: @eth As someone visiting from a search engine I can verify that your assumption was correct, I am glad this was not merged for a duplicate with less optimal SEO.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Ethereum uses Keccak-256](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/550/42), instead of the SHA-3 FIPS 202 standard.  In the sha3 libraries you are using, try looking for the option to specify using Keccak-256.

For Python see [Getting Method ID "Keccak hash" in Python](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11642/getting-method-id-keccak-hash-in-python)

For Javascript, this library [js-sha3](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3)  would involve using the `keccak_256` function instead of `sha3_256`.

```
keccak_256('');
// c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470

sha3_256('');
// a7ffc6f8bf1ed76651c14756a061d662f580ff4de43b49fa82d80a4b80f8434a
```

Others:

```
keccak_256('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
// 4d741b6f1eb29cb2a9b9911c82f56fa8d73b04959d3d9d222895df6c0b28aa15

keccak_256('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
// 578951e24efd62a3d63a86f7cd19aaa53c898fe287d2552133220370240b572d

sha3_256('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
// 69070dda01975c8c120c3aada1b282394e7f032fa9cf32f4cb2259a0897dfc04

sha3_256('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
// a80f839cd4f83f6c3dafc87feae470045e4eb0d366397d5c6ce34ba1739f734d
```

Comment: [As seen in `js-sha3`](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3/blob/c43f9d1d18f9bd220d77c05926122711cb41ad41/src/sha3.js#L23-L24) the only difference is the padding, `0x06` for FIPS202, `0x01` for Keccak-256.

Comment: I'm not sure this comment is accurate: (1) keccak-256 is not a thing (2) see @axic comment bellow for a more correct answer.

Comment: `keccak()` can allow multiple inputs inside the smart contract as: `keccak256(97, 98, 99)`. How could we achieve this using keccak_256() that you represented? @eth♦

Comment: @Alper If you've seen the linked and related questions, I think posting a new and well-written question would be better.  (The answer for your example is to use "abc" but a general answer is better.)

Answer (score 18):

Extending on [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/560/664):

Ethereum uses Keccak hashing, which was submitted to the NIST competition for SHA3. It was subsequently selected as a winner in 2012, but the final standard was only released in August 2015.

Ethereum uses Keccak in its form as it was selected in 2012. Too bad some parameters of the algorithm were tweaked for the final specification in 2015 making it incompatible with the original.

Most tools online implement the final 2015 version of SHA3.

Comment: I'm upvoting but fyi I linked to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550/which-cryptographic-hash-function-does-ethereum-use instead of "rehashing" the NIST stuff :)

Comment: I've totally missed that is a link. I think based on these three-four answers it would make sense to make them into a single wiki page.