# web3.sha3 dealing with hex in both geth and web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

in both geth and web3.js, when we call

```
> web3.sha3("0x536f6d6520415343494920737472696e6720746f20626520686173686564")
```

we get:

```
requirement of using web3.fromAscii before sha3 is deprecated
new usage: 'web3.sha3("hello")'    
see https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/205
if you need to hash hex value, you can do 'sha3("0xfff", true)'
"b21dbc7a5eb6042d91f8f584af266f1a512ac89520f43562c6c1e37eab6eb0c4"
```

So I proceed to do this:

```
> web3.sha3("0x536f6d6520415343494920737472696e6720746f20626520686173686564",true)
```

upon which I get:

```
"bf328f7c064d78daf8fa3e2ffe36c1c3cb22ae02832d4ead2995130ca21a8524"
```

This does not match the original value that I intended to get, namely

```
"b21dbc7a5eb6042d91f8f584af266f1a512ac89520f43562c6c1e37eab6eb0c4"
```

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why the two values are different.  The reason I'm asking is that I'd like to sha3 this:

```
sha3("0xfff")
```

which gives me a invalid byte index error, but I know that

```
sha3("0xfff",true)
```

is not going to get me what I want, based on the above observations.

Comment: When you say the value you "intended to get", what does that mean? The Ethereum sha3 is actually not actually sha3, but the original Keccak. See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tjaden.  By "intended to get" I mean the value at the the of the error message, which is also the same value that we get from a contract running the sha3 code.  Someone kindly pointed out that my software version was out of date, which was causing my issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please **use a newer version of Geth and web3.js**, because the error message you displayed indicates they are old: the error has been [removed](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/commit/b5f8244ff63c96638d9ac4e903e6e43ff81717eb).

The [API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3sha3) is to **use `{encoding: 'hex'}` as the 2nd argument**.  (`true` is not supported anymore and ignored.)

With a newer version, you will get the Keccak-256 hash you are expecting:

```
> web3.sha3("0x536f6d6520415343494920737472696e6720746f20626520686173686564",{encoding:'hex'})
"b21dbc7a5eb6042d91f8f584af266f1a512ac89520f43562c6c1e37eab6eb0c4"
```

For `0xfff`:

```
> web3.sha3('0xfff', {encoding:'hex'})
"004ef40e5e8e6b2638aa35f3fa52d70fb12b25cc067f3476fca2b102ce79f91e"
```

Here is an updated version of Geth which behaves as described above:

```
> web3.version
{
  api: "0.15.1",
```

Comment: This was used in the old version of web3. It might return `web3.sha3 is not a function` in the current version. Using `web3.utils.sha3`.

Comment: @Ender Thank you. Yes, web3.js will keep getting updated, as of this moment there is 1.x and also a branch for 2.x...

Answer (score 6):

You get different output because you're asking `web3.sha3` to interpret your input differently when you pass in `true`.

`web3.sha3("0x536f6d6520415343494920737472696e6720746f20626520686173686564")`

Without the `true`, `web3.sha3` runs `toAscii` on your input before running SHA3 on it. Basically, it tries interpreting the hex pairs in your hex string into ASCII characters and then runs SHA3 on the resulting string. This is also why you get that error when trying to run `web3.sha3('0xfff')`: the hex string isn't composed of hex pairs and so can't be interpreted as representative of an ASCII string.

`web3.sha3("0x536f6d6520415343494920737472696e6720746f20626520686173686564",true)`

With the `true`, it runs SHA3 on your string as-is. Whatever you pass in is exactly what gets passed on to CryptoJS's SHA3 function.