# Hash Test: How to produce hash output

Tags: solidity, sha3

Here is a basic hash test.  I am trying to reproduce the output with: http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_256.html

Is sha3-256 correct?

The output for '1' as the value input is `b10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6` but I cannot reproduce this with the calculator.

```
contract HashTest {

bytes32 public hashOutput;
uint public valueOut;

function hash(uint _values) {
    var value = _values; 
    valueOut = value;
    hashOutput = sha3(value);
}

function refund() {
   msg.sender.send(this.balance);
}
}
```

Also I am using "var" because that is how it was provided in the blind auction example and once I can get the hash to match I will create a more complex function using var if possible.

Comment: Also I did find some other questions surrounding the topic, but none so clear and basic as this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't Solidity sha3 hashes not matching what other sha3 libraries produce?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce)

Comment: It's sort of duplicate.  The other threads do not seem to explicitly answer this question, which is why I constructed it this specific way.

Comment: Added further clarification there: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce/2000#2000

Comment: Keccak-256 that others are suggesting should verify the ethereum sha3 function also does not give the correct output.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice one thing with your source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Solidity the `sha3()` method will use the variable type (as opposed to variable content) to determine the size of it.

`uint` maps to `uint256` and that means in your example not the number `0x01` will be hashed, but `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` is used as input. Use `uint8` for an 8 bit variable (`0x01`).

Also as a reminder, Ethereum uses Keccak and not the final SHA3 ([Why aren't Solidity sha3 hashes not matching what other sha3 libraries produce?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce/2000#2000))

Edit: sample code using [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/axic/ethereumjs-abi):

```
var ABI = require('ethereumjs-abi');
var abi = new ABI();
var BN = require('bn.js')

console.log(abi.soliditySHA3(
    [ 'uint' ],
    [ new BN('01', 16) ]
).toString('hex'));
```

Comment: That is helpful.  Now keccak-256 with input:   `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` 


Produces:  `20ec45d096f1fa2aeff1e3da8a84697d90109524958ed4be9f6d69e37a9140a4`

Comment: Added a sample code, which produces correct results.

Comment: Seems I should be able to put the 63 0's and '1' into the linked calculator under with sha3-256 or at least keccak-256 and come up with the above hash `Oxb10e2....` no?

Comment: @JTicker12 most online calculators won't handle hex input, and treat all input as strings.  If you give 01 to online Keccak-256 calculator, the matching result in Solidity would be to pass the string "01" as in `sha3("01")`.

Comment: @eth yes this is what I needed to know.  Then for testing purposes I will use strings for everything. keccak-256 btw!