# Event tracking and decoding from ethereumj

Tags: events, ethereumj

I have an event in the contract , and upon the event fires I could able to see by a java listener as below

```
public void onTransactionExecuted(TransactionExecutionSummary summary) {
  List<LogInfo> listLogs= summary.getLogs();// This gives you list of log info
 // now Iterate and print the details
}
```

upon printing the loginfo object I get something like `LogInfo{address=cd5805d60bbf9afe69a394c2bda10f6dae2c39af, topics=[37637aa70af5cd14eda4054cc4323408c237c26de60d49064db916e476c29e2e 67fad3bfa1e0321bd021ca805ce14876e50acac8ca8532eda8cbf924da565160 ], data=000000000000000000000000cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826}`.

I know it is some sort of abi encoded or serialized, but I want to decode what are the information I have in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the development guys realized this and started an [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/issues/421), a feature which would solve it.

However I did find the following.

> If arrays (including string and bytes) are used as indexed arguments,
>   the sha3-hash of it is stored as topic instead.

However there is [Hash Test: How to produce hash output](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/hash-test-how-to-produce-hash-output/2002#2002) which mentions it uses  Keccak and not the final SHA3. So the value in the topics above explains what was logged.

Answer (score 3):

In order to parse the information in the LogInfo you will need the contract ABI. Once you have the ABI it's easy to parse :

```
@Override
public void onTransactionExecuted(TransactionExecutionSummary summary) {
  String abi = "[{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint128\"}],\"name\":\"Transfer\",\"type\":\"event\"}]\n";
  for (LogInfo logInfo : summary.getLogs()) {
    CallTransaction.Contract contract = new CallTransaction.Contract(abi);
    CallTransaction.Invocation invocation = contract.parseEvent(logInfo);
    System.out.println(invocation);
  }
}
```

An example of the tests that are used here is [in the DecodeLogTest unit test](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/fce855a12f976d4aa42edee2d80f1331099f50f7/ethereumj-core/src/test/java/org/ethereum/log/DecodeLogTest.java)

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on this exact same issue with the 'input' field of Ethereum transactions. The closest I've come to figuring this out is in Gavin Wood's Yellow Paper (http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) under Appendix 2; Recursive Length Prefixing. I think this is the formatting used, and in some cases it does work for the 'input' field of transactions on the chain, but I'm not sure about events. I "looks" similar.

Comment: Thomas, I actually could able to see the data in the topics section, which is Keccak encoded , I used https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html to see if my data indexed and the hash matches. But appearntly this is one way. Given the hash I can't find the string

Comment: It's definitely one way.