# How do I parse filter log in ethereumj

Tags: ethereumj

As mentioned in this link [How do I parse the transaction receipt log with web3.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js) it works fine for web3 js but how do i parse in **ethereumJ**. [Event tracking and decoding from ethereumj](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/event-tracking-and-decoding-from-ethereumj) I believe it explains about topic and its encoding/decoding details but what I wanted is not about topic but about data variable which comes as one of the parameter in result of filter which holds non indexed values in event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event tracking and decoding from ethereumj](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/event-tracking-and-decoding-from-ethereumj)

Comment: Please make the question clearer, an example might help, and maybe @TheNeoNoirDeveloper will be able to answer.