# How does Solidity's sha3 / keccak256 hash uints?

Tags: solidity, javascript, sha3, hash-algorithm, keccak

This is not a question about the issue with Ethereum using a [non-standard sha3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce). I have found the right JS hashing library, and am able to get matching hashes in JS and Solidity on byte strings. What I am wondering is how to represent a uint when passing it to the JS hash lib so that it results in the same hash as created by Solidity sha3.

```
JS
'0x' + keccak(
  1
)
// 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470

Solidity
sha3(
  1
);
// 0x5fe7f977e71dba2ea1a68e21057beebb9be2ac30c6410aa38d4f3fbe41dcffd2
```

Comment: Update: Solidity's `keccak256` produces identical results to its `sha3` so everything in this thread applies to `keccak256`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Jehan's answer is great, but we need to explain one more thing: Why does `sha3(1)` in solidity produce `b10e2d...fa0cf6`?

This is because solidity's sha3 function hashes its inputs based on the **argument types**. Thus the value `1` will generate a different hash if it is stored as `bytes8`, `bytes16`, `bytes32`, etc. Since `sha3(1)` is being passed `1` as a number literal, it is converted into the smallest necessary type, `uint8`[<sup>1</sup>](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals).

8 bits fit into 2 hex characters, so if you pad your input to 2 characters you will get the same result in web3:

*Javascript:*

```
web3.sha3(leftPad((1).toString(16), 2, 0), { encoding: 'hex' })
// 5fe7f977e71dba2ea1a68e21057beebb9be2ac30c6410aa38d4f3fbe41dcffd2
```

Likewise, you can cast the number on the solidity side:

*Solidity:*

```
// uint is equivalent to uint256
sha3(uint(1))
// b10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6
```

*Javascript:*

```
// note that the value is padded by 64 characters to fit 256 bits
web3.sha3(leftPad((1).toString(16), 64, 0), { encoding: 'hex' })
// b10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6
```

#### A note about `BigNumber` types:

They don't work automatically with `web3.sha3`. You have to convert them to hex first.

*Solidity:*

```
sha3(uint(100 ether))
// c7cc234d21c9cfbd4632749fd77669e7ae72f5241ce5895e410c45185a469273
```

*Javascript:*

```
// the .slice is to remove the leading '0x'
web3.sha3(leftPad(web3.toHex(web3.toWei(100)).slice(2).toString(16), 64, 0), { encoding: 'hex' })
// c7cc234d21c9cfbd4632749fd77669e7ae72f5241ce5895e410c45185a469273
```

#### EDIT:

I wrote a small lib that provides a version of `web3.sha3` that exactly matches the behavior of `sha3` in Solidity. Hopefully this clears up all your hashing woes :).
https://github.com/raineorshine/solidity-sha3

Answer (score 10):

Solidity use HEX values internally.

```
> web3.sha3(web3.toHex(1))
"5fe7f977e71dba2ea1a68e21057beebb9be2ac30c6410aa38d4f3fbe41dcffd2"
```

Comment: I'm getting web3.sha3(web3.toHex(1)) === 8a07523229fdc48491a5e56c76620ba40639eb940e6a2fbdf62b2799b4c86643

Comment: This is not really a full answer, see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Solidity's sha3 function hashes the byte representation of a uint. That is, the number in hex (base 16), padded to 32 bytes. 32 empty bytes in hex representation is 64 zeros.

To do this in JS, we can utilize the infamous left-pad package:

```
const jsHashWeb3 = web3.sha3(leftPad((1).toString(16), 64, 0), { encoding: 'hex' })
// b10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6
```

Comment: In Solidity, `sha3(1)` produces `0x5fe7f9...dcffd2`, not `b10e2d...fa0cf6` as your code produces. Could you explain?

Comment: I know the feeling. Unfortunately I cannot explain. Maybe a typo on my part, it's been a couple of months. I've been using the snippet that I posted about here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/445. It doesn't cover all edge cases, but it's been working for me.