# How to SHA3 strings and integers with Javascript

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to hash two values(integer and string) in contract and get the same hash using these values at backend, but can't quite figure out what to do. Here are contract and JS code below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Contract {
    function hashIt(string a, uint b) returns(bytes32){
        return sha3(a, b);
    }
}
```

**Input:** "1", 1

**Output:** 0x79e6f3a7968620dde8ba64f1f6d03f034d481c27d094c568f6475e60a9dbc4dc

---

```
ethutils.bufferToHex(ethutils.sha3());
```

**Input:** ["1", 1],

**Output:** 0x4535a04e923af75e64a9f6cdfb922004b40beec0649d36cf6ea095b7c4975cae

---

```
web3.sha3()
```

**Input:** "1", 1

**Output:** 0xc89efdaa54c0f20c7adf612882df0950f5a951637e0307cdcb4c672f298b8bc6

Comment: Just a quick idea, converting both into strings and concatenating might help., at least for unifying the input.

Comment: @jeff, In the actual contract I hash timestamps that are generated inside the contract by solidity 'now()' function. It's possible to cast it to string inside the contract, but I believe it involves the use of libraries and should  generally be used as a last resort.

Comment: Yes, I thought you were computing these values with web3. But inside the contract, string manipulation is hard, even [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157648/string-concatenation-in-solidity) in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but I dont have enough reputation to comment.
Have you looked at [How does Solidity's sha3 / keccak256 hash uints?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/) ?