# How can I do abi.encodePacked in Python or PHP?

Tags: abi, python, php

Just concatenating strings doesn't work.

`Keccak::hash(10 . $address, 256)` is what I'm doing atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can concatinate strings simply as shown in the question (that's what abi.encodePacked is doing).

However, my problem was with numbers.

```
This is because solidity's sha3 function hashes its inputs based on the 
argument types. Thus the value 1 will generate a different hash if it is 
stored as bytes8, bytes16, bytes32, etc. Since sha3(1) is being passed 1 as a 
number literal, it is converted into the smallest necessary type, uint81.
```

- [How does Solidity's sha3 / keccak256 hash uints?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-does-soliditys-sha3-keccak256-hash-uints)