# keccak256 Error Undeclared identifier in browser-solidity

Tags: remix, sha3, hash-algorithm, keccak

I try to use `sha3`/`keccak` functions inside a Solidity contract, but I get a weird error:

> Untitled:5:13: Error: Undeclared identifier. 
>   
>  bytes32 d=keccak256(0x616263);

The contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C {

    bytes32 d=keccak256(0x616263);

    bytes32 a=sha3(uint256(1));
}
```

Comment: What version of the Solidity compiler are you using?

Comment: 0.4.3 nightly (in solidity browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `keccak256()` is an alias for the `sha3` function to avoid any [confusion](https://github.com/multiformats/multihash/issues/54) with the sha-3 standard (The opcode is still called SHA3.) this alias was adopted this month so the old compiler don't recognize it.
so use `sha3` instead.

The available hashing functions are `sha3`, `sha256`, `ripemd160`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C { 

    function hashingsha3 (string s)   returns  (bytes32 hash){
        return sha3(s);//<=========
    }

    function hashingsha256 (string s)   returns  (bytes32 hash){
        return sha256(s); //<=========
    }

    function ripemd160 (string s)   returns  (bytes20 hash){
        return ripemd160(s); //<=========
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For browser-solidity, `keccak256` is **fixed in version 0.4.4** and later.

`keccak256` is recommended to use, it's identical to `sha3`, and is less confusing because Ethereum does not use the final SHA-3 standard, but the original winning algorithm named Keccak.  More contracts using `keccak256` will prevent confusion such as
[Why aren't Solidity sha3 hashes not matching what other sha3 libraries produce?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce)