# How to use keccak256 in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, sha3, hash-algorithm, keccak

I have created a Student registration form and taking input as firstName, lastName and studentRegId. Something like this:

```
contract Unique {

string fn;
string ln;
bytes20  val;
bytes32 sId;

function identify(string s, string y, bytes32 i)returns (bytes20){
    fn =s;
    ln =y;
    sId =i;
    val = keccak256(sm,bm,vm);
}

function getOut()constant returns (bytes20 ){
    return val;
}
}
```

This should return a hash value (address). But it is showing the following error:

```
Untitled1:13:25: Error: Undeclared identifier.
    val = keccak256(sm,bm,vm);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

`keccak256` is available in Solidity 0.4.3 and later.

If you're using browser-solidity, Solidity 0.4.4 and later is needed: [keccak256 Error Undeclared identifier in browser-solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/keccak256-error-undeclared-identifier-in-browser-solidity)