# Getting Method ID "Keccak hash" in Python

Tags: contract-development, python, sha3, keccak, hash-algorithm

I am trying to derive the Method ID, the Keccak (SHA-3) hash, in Python so that I may call the functions of my contracts once they are deployed as detailed in the ABI documentation: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI

This details that `0xcdcd77c0` should be the ID derived for the function with the signature `baz(uint32,bool)`

I have tried to replicate this using the python sha3 module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3):

```
>>> import sys
>>> import hashlib
>>> import sha3
>>> s = hashlib.sha3_512()
>>> s.update(b"baz(uint32,bool)")
>>>s.hexdigest()
'f1bb0cbc152d49505684ee7d2a37a860af1820ff8052ed6b32eddd3d82f97e89b24aac5ef334f94474264795cb7672339aecfc2cd2dc1cd0b87adccada2e7bc1'
```

How can I get the first four bytes from this in the correct format to use as a method signature in a transaction? Converting this digest to hex doesn't seem to give the correct signature.

Comment: Ethereum uses 256-bit. Had Python hashlib's sha3 been the same as Ethereum's Keccak, the call should have been: `s = hashlib.sha3_256()`. If you consider updating your post to focus on the wrong library issue (not the wrong use of it at the same time), then s.hexgiest() of your message is `'af54f249a9bc75430f5d7fcc6a2154e9f76ac500e4094c7a2167e43ff7fc53f7'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a recent (>=1.0) version of pysha3 you can recreate the method ID with:

```
from sha3 import keccak_256
sha3_hash = keccak_256("baz(uint32,bool)").hexdigest()
method_id = "0x"+sha3_hash[:8]
print method_id
```

If your pysha3 is old (eg pinned at`pysha3==0.3`) you need:

```
from sha3 import sha3_256
sha3_hash = sha3_256("baz(uint32,bool)").hexdigest()
method_id = "0x"+sha3_hash[:8]
print method_id
```

Explanation: After Ethereum adopted what was then the most recent candidate for SHA3, the standard was changed. What Ethereum uses is now called Keccak instead of SHA3.

Comment: Thanks! My PC had the older version. Bit of a pain that this is the case, I suppose I will eventually have to implement a check to see which version to use.

Comment: Yes, I guess you could do: 
`try:
    from sha3 import keccak_256
except ImportError:
    from sha3 import sha3_256 as keccak_256`

Comment: Something along those lines, just need to rework my normal dependency checking code methinks

Comment: Just to note upon executing the above I did experience the following: ```TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing``` , solved simply by "baz(uint32,bool)".encode('utf-8').  ```keccak_256("baz(uint32,bool)".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()```