# Smart Contract with web3j - Stored SHA hash returned is not the same as input

Tags: evm, web3j, hash, bytes32, hash-algorithm

I have a contract that stores sha-256 hashes of documents (stored as bytes32). I also have a method to retrieve a hash that is mapped to a unique id for the document. However, when I retrieve and compare the hash from the contract, it isn't the same as the hash of the document I sent. The contract is very simple - literally just a getter and a setter - so I'm not manipulating the hash before storing it in any way. Is this a known thing with either the EVM or the web3j library? I can always store the hex string representation of the hash instead of the byte array, but it would still be good to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There is a historical explanation for this. Suffice it to say that there is a procession of algorithm versions in the world at large, in the Solidity compiler's implementations functions and in client-side libraries. It's not going to work unless all parties on all sides are using the same algorithm.

You can have a look at this for more insight: [Why aren't Solidity sha3 hashes not matching what other sha3 libraries produce?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/559/why-arent-solidity-sha3-hashes-not-matching-what-other-sha3-libraries-produce)

This is the sort of problem we can expect in the future, given that all clients in any language will always need to match the algorithm used by the contract - whatever you decide to use today.

How can one help ensure that it will be possible for any client to match what the contract does, *and always will be*?

A solution to that problem is often to expose a `pure` function to help. `pure`, so a client can use it without transmitting sensitive information to the blockchain. (Caveat, if using Infura then it would be sent to their nodes).

```
function hashHelper(bytes memory data, args, etc) public pure returns(bytes32) {
  return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(data, args, etc));
}
```

Use that internally and expose externally so it is convenient for a client to match the contract's process.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have notice the same problem when using bytes32 and solidity sha. It was ok when using string type. You have to use a modified sha lib like this :  https://github.com/raineorshine/solidity-sha3 to match the solidity sha each time.