# Are addresses hashes of public keys, or are they compressed public keys?

Tags: addresses

I understand that in Bitcoin, addresses are hashed public keys. However, I've also heard that compressed public keys are just as short as hashes while maintaining their 1:1 relationship.

Does Ethereum use hashed public keys, or compressed public keys, for addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Public Key is hashed with SHA-3 to produce a 256-bit output. The upper 96 bits are discarded, and the lower 160 bits become the Address.

[Source](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/563/questions-on-public-addresses)

Thus, addresses do not seem to preserve all of the information in the public key.

Answer (score 5):

Ethereum uses hashed public keys.  It does not use compressed public keys.

Important note is that [Ethereum uses Keccak-256](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/550/42) instead of the SHA-3 standard.

[Sample Python code:](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/keys.py#L282)

```
def privtoaddr(x):
    if len(x) > 32:
        x = decode_hex(x)
    return sha3(bitcoin.privtopub(x)[1:])[12:]  # sha3 here is Keccak-256
```

1. The public key is computed from the private key
2. Public key is hashed with Keccak-256
3. The upper 12 bytes (96 bits) of the Keccak-256 output is discarded.