# What is the cheapest hash function available in solidity?

Tags: solidity, gas, sha3, hash-algorithm, keccak

AFAIK there are 3 hash functions to choose from in solidity (`sha3`, `sha256`, and `ripemd`). sha3 is native while the others use precompiled contracts.

Which one of these is cheapest (in terms of gas)?

Comment: Your questions is slightly ambiguous. You could improve your question by specifying what you mean with "cheap". I assume you mean "which hashing algorithm has the lowest gas cost?" (Cheap can also mean in terms of computational power).

Comment: @JeffreyW. done

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`keccak256` (new alias for `sha3`) is cheapest.

Source: [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper)

Appendix G mentions the gas cost of `sha3` is:

- 30 gas + 6 gas for each word (rounded up) for input data to a SHA3 Keccak-256 operation.

---

Appendix E has the costs for the others.

`sha256` (SHA2-256) costs:

- 60 gas + 12 gas for each word (rounded up) for input data to a SHA2-256 operation.

`ripemd` is even more expensive:

- 600 gas + 120 gas for each word (rounded up) for input data to a RIPEMD-160 operation.

Comment: It's worth noting that calls to the `sha3` built-in function (as opposed to the assembly directive) currently appear to create a contract invocation in Solidity, which is much more expensive than it needs to be.

Comment: @NickJohnson Sounds like a good question to ask if it is invoking a contract.  (I kept my answer to the Yellow Paper, since values in an empirical, implementation dependent answer could change over time.)

Comment: @NickJohnson how do we know how we're calling it? is it the difference between `blah = sha3(blah blah)` and `assembly { blah = sha3(blahblahblah) }` ?

Comment: @bekah That's right; but how it works may well have changed since I wrote that comment.

Comment: Can someone confirm if this is still the case?

Comment: `sha3` is not exactly `keccak256`. Ethereum source code for `keccak256` confirms it.

Comment: @TharinduMadushanka Do you mean https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550/which-cryptographic-hash-function-does-ethereum-use ?

Comment: Yes. Just to note that it's not same as `sha3`. "The Ethereum hashing function, keccak256, sometimes (erroneously) called `sha3`"
https://github.com/ethereum/eth-hash

Comment: @NickJohnson This does not appear to be the case anymore. I tried hashing something via `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(...))` and via `assembly {c := keccak256(add(encoded, 0x20), 40)}`. The assembly version actually ended up costing 11 gas more.