# Alternative to sequence id for mapping

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-design, synchronization

Right now I have a sequence if ids used for mapping in contract:

```
mapping (uint => Document) documents;
uint documentsCount;
```

which is incremented for every new document:

```
function createDocument() returns (uint docId) {
    docId = documentsCount++;
    documents[docId] = Document(...);
    Created(msg.sender, docId);
}
```

When I make this call I receive a transaction id (`tx_id`), which is uniq and finalized if I understand correctly. Also I can get `docId` if I listen for `Created` events.

This `docId` depends on execution order, and in distributed systems such as Ethereum, we should wait until it's finalized in blockchain.

I wonder what should I do if I want to use it as a reference in further transactions? Say I have `addSignature(uint docId, bytes sign)` transaction next to it. Or simple read, like `getState(unit docId)`.

If I call it just after first transaction, it still possible that in blockchain it will be executed against different block and wrong document. Or what if pass this `docId` to a different machine which can have slightly different order or transactions at this moment.

What is a best practice to generate a reference id at this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea could be to use `sha3` (of the document) for `docId`.

The mapping would become:
`mapping (bytes32 => Document) documents;`

[`sha3` is the cheapest hash function.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3184/42)