# What is the gas cost of keccak256("abc")?

Tags: solidity, gas, keccak, sha3

According to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3200), the gas cost of `keccak256` is:

> 30 gas + 6 gas for each word (rounded up) for input data to a SHA3 Keccak-256 operation

I'm assuming that the size of a word is 256 bits and the size of a character is 8 bits.

Hence the gas cost `keccak256("abc")` or any other string of up to 32 characters is 36 gas units.

Is my assumption correct?

If yes, is my conclusion correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly correct, except for the empty string.

`keccak256("")` costs 30 gas.

`keccak256("0")` costs 36 gas.

`keccak256("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")` still costs 36 gas.

`keccak256("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF_")` costs 42 gas.

These gas costs do not include costs other than the actual `KECCAK256` opcode, such as pushing the pointer and length of the input onto the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, no null-character issue (i.e., a string of 32 characters would cost 40 gas units)?

Comment: @goodvibration No, 32 characters costs 36 gas. Solidity stores the length of the string before the actual string characters. It does not use a null terminator like C.