# Is Ethereum's mining algorithm vulnerable to ASICBOOST?

Tags: mining, bitcoin, hash-algorithm

Bitcoin's hashing algorithm uses a multi-step hashing function. Some miners have used a technique referred to as ASICBOOST to exploit this. I'm unclear on the specifics, but it has something to do with the way headers are broken into chunks and those chunks can be re-used to speed up hashing.

Does Ethereum and its hashing algorithm have *similar* (obviously not exactly the same) issue?

Comment: Some more context about ASICBOOST would improve this question.

Comment: @eth I've updated

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, no.

AsicBoost [works by](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/43620/27622)...

> "...speeding up Bitcoin mining in general (for ASICs and CPUs alike)
>   by reducing the frequency of computing one part of the SHA-256
>   calculation."

So AsicBoost is keyed specifically for SHA-256 calculations, with SHA-256 itself being a member of the SHA-2 family of crytographic hash functions.

Ethereum doesn't use SHA-256: it uses KECCAK-256, which [doesn't actually follow the SHA-3 standards](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/554/52) as its name suggests it should, but *is* presumably sufficiently different to render AsicBoost ineffective: it's a completely different hashing algorithm.

Comment: This is definitely true, but its not clear to me that keccak256/ethash doesn't have the same problem as sha256. I meant a more general question, as in does the vulnerability*in sha256 as used in the bitcoin PoW algorithm apply to Etheruem

Comment: There's this paper which has a more detailed explanation http://www.mit.edu/~jlrubin//public/pdfs/Asicboost.pdf . The technique uses a quirk of sha-256 plus block header alignment plus transactions merkles-tree. Since Ethereum uses a differente hash this will not work as is, but you can try to apply the idea behind it. Although the switch to POS will likely render such research useless.