# Difference between keccak256 and sha3

Tags: hash, keccak, hash-algorithm

I have been reviewing keccak256 implementation and sha3-256 that follows the FIPS standard.  The sponge function is taking a while to set in, but I have noticed a difference in implementation :

I noticed web3.js uses crypto-js implementation of sha3: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/sha3.js
From that  I gather the  var LFSR = 0x01;

which is set to 0x06 in sha3-256.  Am I correct in this observation?

What other differences are there?

Comment: I have confirmed with test cases that this is the fundamental difference in the 2 algorithms.  I have also tested with Solidity.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550/which-cryptographic-hash-function-does-ethereum-use

Answer (score 18, accepted):

from an answer to [What are the key differences between the draft SHA-3 standard and the Keccak submission?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15727/what-are-the-key-differences-between-the-draft-sha-3-standard-and-the-keccak-sub):

> 1. No they did not, the internals and security levels have not been
>      changed from the draft Keccak submission, only the padding rule has
>      changed.
> 2. The padding change is the only difference, this allows
>      future tree hashing modes as well as the current SHAKE outputs to
>      generate different digests given the same security parameters and
>      message inputs. Up to 4 additional bits are added, which keeps the
>      full padding inside a byte boundary, making implementations with
>      octet only input able to switch to SHA-3 from Keccak with change to
>      only a single line of code.
> 3. The padding change has no negative impact on the security of SHA-3.

Answer (score 7):

> Keccak and sha-3 are not the same. In 2007, U.S. National Institute of
> Standard and Technology (NIST) initiated a competition about SHA-3. In
> 2012, Keccak team won the competition. From then on, developers
> implemented lots of “sha3” solution based on Keccak. However, in 2014,
> NIST modified Keccak solution and released FIPS 202, and this updated
> proposal becomes official SHA-3 standard on Aug 2015. Many “old”
> program still use Keccak, and do not upgrade to official SHA-3
> standard.
>
> “old” code based on Keccak does not generate the same hash value as
> SHA-3 does. So, if using a “sha3” library, you should be crystal clear
> that the library is based on Keccak or based on standard SHA-3. A
> simple solution is doing a test for empty input:

SHA-3 standard output is:

```
a7ffc6f8bf1ed76651c14756a061d662f580ff4de43b49fa82d80a4b80f8434a
```

Many old Keccak-256 outputs are:

```
c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470
```

from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-blockchain/9781788839044/01de5937-ff22-43f0-956e-cf8ae2ebf876.xhtml)

> The key idea behind SHA-3 is based on unkeyed permutations, as opposed
> to other typical hash function constructions that used keyed
> permutations. Keccak also does not make use of the Merkle- Damgard
> transformation that is commonly used to handle arbitrary-length input
> messages in hash functions. A newer approach, called sponge and
> squeeze construction, is used in Keccak. It is a random permutation
> model. Different variants of SHA-3 have been standardized, such as
> SHA3-224, SHA3-256, SHA3-384, SHA3-512, SHAKE128, and SHAKE256

If you ever used this:

```
  web3.utils.soliditySha3()
```

eben though name is Sha3 but its actually implemented by keccak256