# how to compare strings in solidity?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract test2 
{

    address creater;
    string username;
    string password;

    function testusernamepassword(string username,string password) returns (bool) 
    {
        if (username == "deepak" && password == "123") //error: operator == is not compatible with string ?
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 65):

You can compare strings like this:

```
function compareStrings(string memory a, string memory b) public view returns (bool) {
    return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked((b))));
}
```

As a side note: It's not secure at all dealing with passwords and usernames in Solidity.

Comment: keccak256 is Ethereum's native hash function. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/554/229

Comment: Note, this emits a warning in Remix. https://imgur.com/a/ruV6IM1

Comment: Gives following error: `equires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...) to obtain the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI encoding.` @pabloruiz55

Comment: @alper That is because of changes in Solidity since 2017. Keccak used to take a tuple of values, now it takes only one. Abi.encodePacked will take a tuple and produce an array of bytes encoding all the elements of that tuple, making it suitable for Keccak.

Comment: casting to bytes type uses less gas (see Merunas and Joel solution)

Answer (score 18):

Here's the simplest way:

```
keccak256(bytes(a)) == keccak256(bytes(b));
```

Just use `keccak256()` while converting the string to `bytes`.

Comment: For checking empty string: `keccak256(bytes(a)) == keccak256(bytes(""));` will not work. Better: `string memory empty = "";` then `keccak256(bytes(a)) == keccak256(bytes(empty));`

Comment: Good point you can also compare empty strings with `length` like so `bytes(<your-string>).length == 0`

Answer (score 11):

Seems kind of expensive for strings that have a different length, which could be *most* of the time.  What about this solution?

```
    function memcmp(bytes memory a, bytes memory b) internal pure returns(bool){
        return (a.length == b.length) && (keccak256(a) == keccak256(b));
    }
    function strcmp(string memory a, string memory b) internal pure returns(bool){
        return memcmp(bytes(a), bytes(b));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings are not really a primitive type in Solidity. There are lots of things that are missing, a bit like in old C. They are a lot like a bytes array, so the low level of comparing would be to treat them as such and iterate over the arrays.

PabloRuiz's answer is a better choice.

If you want to know a little more about strings, you could try my [blog post](http://coders-errand.com/working-with-strings-in-solidity/) on that subject.

Regarding testing user names and passwords in Solidity, keep in mind that everything you send in a transaction is visible to everyone. The data can be retrieved from a [blockchain explorer](https://etherscan.io/). The first thing you should try, at least, is to Hash the password, but even then, who ever finds the hash can copy it and relay it for themselves in a fake authentication. In non-blockchain systems, you'd usually use some kind of challenge-response setup. 
If you could give more details about your authentication setup, people here might be able to give some ideas around it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleaner version of @pabloruiz55 version. The parenthesis are not necessary and the function can be pure.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StringComparison {

    function compareStrings(string memory a, string memory b) public pure returns (bool) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b));
    }
}
```

Directly try out the code in Remix [here](https://remix.ethereum.org/?#code=Ly8gU1BEWC1MaWNlbnNlLUlkZW50aWZpZXI6IE1JVAoKcHJhZ21hIHNvbGlkaXR5IF4wLjguMDsKCmNvbnRyYWN0IFN0cmluZ0NvbXBhcmlzb24gewogICAgZnVuY3Rpb24gY29tcGFyZVN0cmluZ3Moc3RyaW5nIG1lbW9yeSBhLCBzdHJpbmcgbWVtb3J5IGIpIHB1YmxpYyBwdXJlIHJldHVybnMgKGJvb2wpIHsKICAgICAgICByZXR1cm4ga2VjY2FrMjU2KGFiaS5lbmNvZGVQYWNrZWQoYSkpID09IGtlY2NhazI1NihhYmkuZW5jb2RlUGFja2VkKGIpKTsKICAgIH0KfQ==).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Openzeppelin in your project, go ahead and use their function in `Strings.sol` library:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/6e214227376acd688e60fcdca8cb7f0ae8cef98f/contracts/utils/Strings.sol#L90-L92

Answer (score 0):

I actually just built and published a library for dealing with strings in a more traditional way. I have most common js string functions including includes(compareString) and equals(compareString).

To use my library on your local machine:

Install the @tw3/solidity package. (Skip this for Remix IDE users)

```
npm install @tw3/solidity
```

Import into your smart contract:

```
import “@tw3/solidity/contracts/utils/String.sol”
```

Use it for all string variables:

```
contract MyContract {
    using String for string;

    function stringsEqual(string memory a, string memory b) public pure returns (bool) {
        return a.equals(b);
    }
}
```

I’ve currently got the following functions assume string=“strings!”:

1. string.length() // 8
2. string.charAt(1) // t
3. string.startsWith(“str”) // true
4. string.endsWith(“ing”) // false
5. string.includes(“z”) // false
6. string.equals(“strings!”) // true
7. string.indexOf(“s”) // 0
8. string.lastIndexOf(“s”) // 6
9. string.slice(2,-1) // rings
10. string.split(“i”) // [str,ngs!]
11. string.toLowerCase() // strings!
12. strings.toUpperCase() // STRINGS!

Have fun and good luck! Anyone who wants to contribute to my library feel free to find my GitHub repo TechnicallyWeb3/tw3-solidity