# How can I comparing fingerprint using solidity language?

Tags: solidity, nodejs, ethereumjs

I have a fingerprint image stored in IPFS and I want to compare with another fingerprint image, because i need to know if is the same fingerprint ,is there some way, some lib that i can compare this images using solidity language?

Comment: You wouldn't want to compare actual fingerprints but hashes of said fingerprints which must align. However, I'm not certain how this is done. I think you would need some way of fuzzy hashing and comparing to see if these fingerprints match for a certain percentage.

Comment: For comparing strings: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30912/how-to-compare-strings-in-solidity