# Compare bytes32 and string using solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I need to compare a bytes32 value with a string. In the below example I need to check if QRVal==QRScanVal.

Eg: bytes32 QRVal="0xc59aa6848d32d073bdcaa041b2735d3e4546d0836498e30de7c4c64c50933a33";

string memory QRScanVal="0xc59aa6848d32d073bdcaa041b2735d3e4546d0836498e30de7c4c64c50933a33";

I'm a newbie with solidity any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a very strong argument and the situation is unavoidable I would recommend that you avoid this conversion in the contract.

It is perfectly reasonable to insist that client-side software accommodate the contract and not the other way around. A partial list of reasons:

1. Contracts are (generally) **immutable**. This raises the importance of QA. A first line of defense is maximum simplicity. The conversion function may indeed be okay (or not) but it certainly is a lot for reviewers/auditors/attackers to think about.
2. Gas **cost**. All those ops will be replicated by all full nodes and a significant cost to everyone who uses the contract. The conversion function is well-suited to off-chain preprocessing in clients/servers where processing capacity is plentiful and nearly free.

I can think of a case where the inputs come from two different contracts and you want the comparison to happen on-chain.

**TL;DR;**

If it is possible to avoid this, then you should avoid it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I will think of a redesign.

Comment: "I can think of a case where the inputs come from two different contracts and you want the comparison to happen on-chain."- this is exactly the scenario we have here. QRScanVal is the value sent for comparison to contract, after we scan from the QRCode of a retail product.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you found the answers helpful please support the site with votes the useful answers. https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/vote-early-vote-often

Answer (score 1):

You can convert bytes32 into string and then compare it
Here is the link to how to convert bytes32 into string

[How to convert a bytes32 to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string)

Here is the link to compare two string

[how to compare strings in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30912/how-to-compare-strings-in-solidity)

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks Rishabh for your input. I did tried the snippet however it did not work for me. the QRVal is a SHA256. Whereas my QRScanVal, is a scanned string value coming in from a QRCode on a product. (The solidity code is being used on Azure workbench, if the input helps.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your address to string as below,

```
string memory canAddress = toAsciiString(QRVal);

//Functions to convert the address to string
function toAsciiString(address x) public returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory s = new bytes(40);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            bytes1 b = bytes1(uint8(uint256(uint160(x)) / (2**(8 * (19 - i)))));
            bytes1 hi = bytes1(uint8(b) / 16);
            bytes1 lo = bytes1(uint8(b) - 16 * uint8(hi));
            s[2 * i] = char(hi);
            s[2 * i + 1] = char(lo);
        }
        return string(abi.encodePacked("0x", s));
    }

function char(bytes1 b) public returns (bytes1 c) {

    if (uint8(b) < 10) return bytes1(uint8(b) + 0x30);
    else return bytes1(uint8(b) + 0x57);
}
```