# What is the return of uint(keccak256(_str));?

Tags: solidity, hash, keccak, randomness, uint256

I'm doing the chapter 1 of the crypto zombies course.

```
        uint id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna)) - 1;
        NewZombie(id, _name, _dna);
    }

    function _generateRandomDna(string _str) private view returns (uint) {
        uint rand = uint(keccak256(_str));
        return rand % dnaModulus;
    }
```

the return of this is supposed to be a number of 16 numbers. per exemple "8356281049284737".
But for `return rand % dnaModulus;` . but i cant figure out what is the return of `uint(keccak256(_str))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keccak256 is the EVM hash function that is used in Ethereum. It's quite [similar to SHA3-256](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/554/33305). You can also use this hash function outside of the EVM with tools like Web3js, ethers.js or just try it online [here](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html). In Solidity the call will return a hash in bytes32 form which can then easily be converted to a number by casting it to uint256.