# How can I check if an Ethereum address is valid?

Tags: ether, addresses, checksum, public-key

I've read many times that you should never **input an address** by hand unless you want to accidentally send `Ether` into **no-mans-land**. I'd like to know what those checksums might be.

1. Is there a way to tell a typo is occurred?
2. How, and what are the formatting rules to it?

Im asking so I can potentially create a wrapper function that checks for these things before submitting to the network.

Comment: Related https://medium.com/@piyopiyo/how-to-convert-ethereum-address-to-checksum-address-cd3e2305e2fc

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### Updates (June 2023)

`web3.utils.isAddress` will soon [be deprecated](https://docs.web3js.org/api/web3-utils/function/isAddress). Please use [`web3-validator`](https://docs.web3js.org/api/web3-validator/function/isAddress) package instead. Example:

```js
import { isAddress } from 'web3-validator';

isAddress('blah');
```

### Using a Library (June 2016)

Libraries like [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io) and [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/) have `isAddress()`.

Examples:

- `ethers.utils.isAddress('0x8ba1f109551bd432803012645ac136ddd64dba72');` // true
- `web3.utils.isAddress('blah');` // false

The following is an answer from 2016.

### Regular Address

[EIP 55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/55) added a ["capitals-based checksum"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/267/why-dont-ethereum-addresses-have-checksums) which was implemented by Geth by May 2016.
Here's [Javascript code from Geth:](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/aa9fff3e68b1def0a9a22009c233150bf9ba481f/jsre/ethereum_js.go)

```js
/**
 * Checks if the given string is an address
 *
 * @method isAddress
 * @param {String} address the given HEX adress
 * @return {Boolean}
*/
var isAddress = function (address) {
    if (!/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/i.test(address)) {
        // check if it has the basic requirements of an address
        return false;
    } else if (/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/.test(address) || /^(0x)?[0-9A-F]{40}$/.test(address)) {
        // If it's all small caps or all all caps, return true
        return true;
    } else {
        // Otherwise check each case
        return isChecksumAddress(address);
    }
};

/**
 * Checks if the given string is a checksummed address
 *
 * @method isChecksumAddress
 * @param {String} address the given HEX adress
 * @return {Boolean}
*/
var isChecksumAddress = function (address) {
    // Check each case
    address = address.replace('0x','');
    var addressHash = sha3(address.toLowerCase());
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {
        // the nth letter should be uppercase if the nth digit of casemap is 1
        if ((parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) > 7 && address[i].toUpperCase() !== address[i]) || (parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) <= 7 && address[i].toLowerCase() !== address[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

### ICAP Address

ICAP has a checksum which can be verified.  You can review [Geth's icap.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2db97986460c57ba74a563d97a704a45a270df7d/common/icap.go) and here's a snippet from it:

```js
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN
func validCheckSum(s string) error {
    s = join(s[4:], s[:4])
    expanded, err := iso13616Expand(s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    checkSumNum, _ := new(big.Int).SetString(expanded, 10)
    if checkSumNum.Mod(checkSumNum, Big97).Cmp(Big1) != 0 {
        return ICAPChecksumError
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Out of curiosity, any idea how good the checksum is? meaning with a few wrong digits, what are the chances it passes the checksum coincidentally anyway?

Comment: EIP 55 compares the regular address checksum with ICAP: "On average there will be 15 check bits per address, and the net probability that a randomly generated address if mistyped will accidentally pass a check is 0.0247%. This is a ~50x improvement over ICAP, but not as good as a 4-byte check code."

Comment: It would be nice to be able to check for validity in Solidity as well.  One way to do this would be to transfer a tiny amount of ether to any new address you create, and check for non-zero balance in Solidity.  (Should that be a separate question?)

Comment: @eth While using the regular address function I'm getting a `ReferenceError: sha3 is not defined` error, any idea why?

Comment: @PedroLobito For sha3, you can use `keccak256` from a library like https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3  I have not been able to find the recent code that Geth uses to improve this answer.

Comment: I'll do that, tks!

Comment: `sha3` function is not defined. It is used in function checkSumAddress in the aswer. `var addressHash = sha3(address.toLowerCase());`

Comment: @DenisMatafonov You're asking the same as Pablo did... https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid/1379?noredirect=1#comment30449_1379

Comment: @eth it wasnt a question, it was a remark that code, provided in the asnwer is not valid. And worst of all, that it _does_ work most of the time, except cases when address doesnt fall into fiorst and second `if` and `else if`. Link to sha3 lib should be included in the answer.

Comment: @eth I am trying to use this lib https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA for `sha3`, but looks like it doesn't work with your code. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Does this also works for smart-contract's address? @eth

Comment: @Alper Yes a smart contract address can be capitalized according to EIP 55, [example](https://etherscan.io/address/0x281055afc982d96fab65b3a49cac8b878184cb16).

Comment: bad answer, this code fails on validation of even valid addresses!
the next answer with web3.utils.isAddress is much better and easier

Comment: @OleksandrGrin Thanks for your comment. I would also use a library; I've modified this answer to show 2 examples.

Answer (score 52):

There is an easier way now with `web3`:

Naive:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#isaddress

```
web3.utils.isAddress('0xc1912fee45d61c87cc5ea59dae31190fffff232d');
> true
```

OR
Better version
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#tochecksumaddress

```js
try {
  const address = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(rawInput)
} catch(e) { 
  console.error('invalid ethereum address', e.message) 
}
```

using checkSum method is better because you will always deal with data and never have to lowerCase.

Comment: The isaddress() method also checks for checksum! why do we need go with checkSum method?

Comment: `isAddress`:
_`Checks if a given string is a valid Ethereum address. It will also check the checksum, if the address has upper and lowercase letters.`_
As @atul stated

Answer (score 9):

The standard 40 character hex addresses now have a checksum in the form of capitalization. If the address has at least one capital letter then it is checksummed and, if inputted on a site that checks the sum, it will return false if it's not a valid address.

The scheme is as follows:

> convert the address to hex, but if the ith digit is a letter (ie. it's one of abcdef) print it in uppercase if the ith bit of the hash of the address (in binary form) is 1 otherwise print it in lowercase

You can read VBs full writeup here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/55

Answer (score 8):

```
function validateInputAddresses(address) {
        return (/^(0x){1}[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$/i.test(address));
}
```

Comment: This just test plausibility, doesn't validate the checksum. It still seems to be a better way to write the plausibility test regex.

Answer (score 4):

The python package 'ethereum' has a function called 'check_checksum' in the utils module:

```
from ethereum.utils import check_checksum
check_checksum('0xc1912fee45d61c87cc5ea59dae31190fffff232d')
> True
```

I build a small project for this which i use programmatically in my apps. It has a 'micro' api:

```
https://balidator.io/api/ethereum/0xea0258D0E745620e77B0A389e3A656EFdb7Cf821
```

It also has address validation for bitcoin, monero, and ripple.

You can find the documentation here: [balidator.io/api-documentation](https://balidator.io/api/documentation)

Comment: The python Web3 library also has address checking methods. https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html?highlight=isaddress#Web3.isAddress

Comment: balidator.io is not found

Answer (score 2):

So far ether addresses have no checksum and are simply the HEX encoding of the address bytes. There is however a proposal for encoding and checksum, see: [ICAP: Inter exchange Client Address Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol).

ICAP has preliminary support merged in some Ethereum client.

Answer (score 2):

Checksums are mechanisms to prevent sending funds to wrong addresses (set by mistake or by a malicious party).

#### Programmatically

You can use `web3`'s amazing utils:

> web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(value)

The function above works only if you have version `1.0.0` or above.

#### Web

I created an online tool, check it out here: [EthSum](https://ethsum.netlify.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check is if you also have the public key of the ethereum address. The Ethereum Foundation's official `eth-keys` Python library can be used, and is now part of their Github repo and can be [seen here](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-keys) and contains a suite of tools that include ways to check address validity, such as using the `PublicKey().checksum_address()` method (see below example).

The following method requires the uncompressed public key in bytes format, which means it would have to be only for accounts you have the public-key data for:

```
 >>>from eth_keys import keys
 
 >>>keys.PublicKey(b'\x98\xbb\xfa\xdd\xbc\xc7\xab\x14\xa3\x9c\xb4\x84\xbf\x94MO\xf5\x91^G\xc1\xc2\x0b\xe77t\xc3\xd0\x05\x12|Z\xf5\x17PZ\x97\xe2\\`IR\xc1\xbd\x10\xa3\xa3\xdf\xbf0\xaf;7\xc0z\xbc\xc7\x0b\x9c\xbd<FY\x98').to_checksum_address()
        
        '0x28f4961F8b06F7361A1efD5E700DE717b1db5292'
```

Comment: It should be `from eth_keys import keys`. I would have edited, but edits must be at least six characters.

Comment: @JoshDavis you are absolutley right! Thanks for the note I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Or in Python (with [Web3py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html))

```
from web3 import Web3

print(Web3.isAddress("0xBB9923E927F0bC33C901396F4C589B43DB991705"))
```