# Reclaim Ether from Fail / Cancelled transaction

Tags: ether, coinbase

I tried to transfer Ether from my Coinbase account to somebody but the recipient declined it for a technical issue. Therefore, the status of the transaction is now *cancelled* with TxReceipt Status as “Fail” from Etherscan page.

However, the coin is NOT restored to my Coinbase account yet, and Coinbase support says that it is lost for good and there's no way that I can reclaim it.

Is this really true? Or can anyone tell me how can I reclaim this to my account?

Comment: Please share the tx hash so we can look it up on Etherscan.

Comment: @pabloruiz55 thanks for your comment. tx hash value is 0x581a5303beb776df3d363866a22de0e340ae6be63fe636f044983e685b060ea9

Comment: This may help you understand your problem: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4072/are-funds-returned-if-one-transfers-from-an-exchange-to-an-invalid-ethereum-addr/31866#31866

Comment: @kjee the transaction hash you shared is invalid. Are you sure you entered it correctly? where did you get it? https://etherscan.io/tx/0x581a5303beb776df3d363866a22de0e340ae6be63fe636f044983e685b%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B060ea9

Comment: @pabloruiz55 sorry for the confusion. This is an url for the transaction. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x581a5303beb776df3d363866a22de0e340ae6be63fe636f044983e685b060ea9

Comment: It doesn't appear to be lost for good. The other questions are off-topic, though.

Comment: Dear @lungj thanks for your response. Would you elaborate a bit more about your comment? Is there any way that I can reclaim the coin without knowing the private key?

Comment: The account is a regular account that has the ether. That means that whoever (if anyone still does) has the private key that corresponds to the account, the ether can be retrieved. The rest of the questions are third-party support questions and thus off topic for this stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "the coin" is not restored... You mean the 4.20xx ether you sent?

From seeing the account I can say you did get back the 4.20xxx ether that were sent to the failed transaction. 
https://etherscan.io/address/0x2c2ff4ccd958954c5a5802c8cf81555d936f78ca
The account has that very same balance.

You received 2 transactions that total 1001 ether and then sent 3 transactions that total that same amount. The smaller one of 4.20 ether failed and that is the balance the account currently has.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this. However, honestly, this account a new one for me and have no idea where it is associated with. Would you give me a guidance regarding how to claim this coins?

Comment: If this account is yours, then you should have the private key associated with it that would allow you to make transactions. I'm not sure what you are asking for, sorry.

Comment: @pabloruiz55 it seems the wallet has a logic to transfer ethers that is not clear for us. If you follow the transactions, you can´t end it. I tried a couple of address to see where it ends and I couldn´t find it. And it has a pattern. 2 big amount transfer and 2 small. Maybe kjee doesn´t have the private key

Comment: @LuizSoares Yes. The transaction is handled by Coinbase and I don't have a private key for this address.

Comment: @kjee I fear you are out of luck. You should never make a transaction to a smart contract with an account you don't own the private keys to.