# understanding etherscan.io blockchain explorer (ropsten)

Tags: transactions, explorers, etherscan, ropsten

I am new to eth. I tried to explore the blockchain using etherscan.
For the record, here is my eth address: 
[image]
(0x757e0617fae3050242ddd13e2117ef1c62fdaf4d).

There are three things in etherscan's page that I don't understand. 
[image]

1. (screenshot 2) I paid out some of the eth I had received from a faucet to other accounts (one of them is mine, another is that of the faucet). This translate in the balance being less than 3. But only one transaction (the original payment from the faucet) appears in this block explorer. **Why is it that the balance is in line with the transaction history I know, but the outgoing transactions themselves do not appear?**
2. (screenshot 2) **Why is my address capitalized the way it is on etherscan.io, in contrast to what I see in the geth console? [ANSWERED: see comments]**
3. (screenshot 3) **An address on which I sent eth shows a positive balance, but no transaction history. How can this be?**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: For #2, the capitalization is a checksum (http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid) and can be a safer version than the all lowercase version.  For #1 and #3, what are the transaction hashes you expect to see?  What does the explorer show for them?

Comment: Thx for this answer. Hashes are: ['0x0fdf6055c54a028f72c926378b63854db3060111902e6140761970ea0b8eb107', '0x79e9b27903f4f69f0224f02885d53b50381337d268f9a5276b124820cb1bee1f', '0x0fdf6055c54a028f72c926378b63854db3060111902e6140761970ea0b8eb107'] insofar as this was returned by my 'sendTransaction(from, to, amnt)' calls. The block explorer does not find any match for these. V. grateful for help.