# I created a offline paper ethereum wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain, contract-design, private-blockchain, contract-deployment

I have been trying for days to try check this paper wallet to see if it has a balance so I can know if it is safe to move more ethereum to it please 
My public address 0x9826eb8a401e88e121243e879e6f5442e4ec09de

Comment: This is probably a duplicate by the way. You could have easily found this answer by searching first and then asking your question. Generally that's what you should do so as to keep the information content high and the number of questions low.

Comment: It mainly depends if you already have transfered eth to this account otherwise you can't see it on any chain explorer because your account is only generated locally. To check if your address is valid, just send a small amount to it. Otherwise you can also look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid

Answer (score 1):

You can always check on online blockchain scraper like Etherscan. Here's the list of transactions against the address you provided: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9826eb8a401e88e121243e879e6f5442e4ec09de

While this method is "pretty safe," it's not as safe as waiting until your local node sync and getting the transactions directly from that node (as your local wallet -- probably Mist -- does).  The trouble with the local wallet, especially when you first enter the space, is that it takes a very long time to sync the whole blockchain.

The trouble with the remote (centralized) Etherscan is that it's centralized, and therefore potentially open to manipulation (although I've never seen anything to suggest that in the case of EtherScan.

What we all really need is a fully decentralized blockchain scraper, but that's not yet available...

Comment: Thomas, we have Quickblocks known as ethslurp before  https://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/quickBlocks

Comment: Thanks so much for your time I really appreciate it. It has been a bit daunting for me

Comment: @IgorBarinov Yes. EthSlurp is now part of QuickBlocks. A small part.