# Solidity documentation: Are 39 or 41 digit long address literals allowed?

Tags: solidity, addresses

Solidity documentation [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#address-literals) says that

> Hexadecimal literals that are between 39 and 41 digits long and do not pass the checksum test produce an error.

Do they mean, *"Hexadecimal literals that are 40 digits long and do not pass the checksum test produce an error."*?

If not, then why does the language include 41 & 39?

Based on [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid) it seems clear that address is always 40 digits long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cameel](https://github.com/cameel) beautifully answered it [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12992#issuecomment-1120853432).

Comment: Hi Sourabh! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Link only answer are discouraged. Please include the essential part in the answer and use the link to provide more details.