# What's the best way to verify an address is correct in C#?

Tags: blockchain, addresses, data-types, c#, data

Is there an easy way to validate an Ethereum address in `C#`?

Basically, I am looking for the method that correspond to [these ones in `Javascript`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid) but in `C#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `C#`, you can use this method from the `Nethereum` NuGet package:

```
/// <summary>
/// Validates if the hex string is 40 alphanumeric characters
/// </summary>
public bool IsValidEthereumAddressHexFormat(string address)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return false;
    return address.HasHexPrefix() && IsValidAddressLength(address) &&
           address.IsHex();
}
```