# What's the point of IBAN addresses?

Tags: transactions, web3js, icap, api-design

I've been reading through web3.js's API [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) and come across transactions using [IBAN](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendibantransaction) numbers. They appear to be alphanumerical values generated from the public address.

What is their role since they're not used for confidentiality reasons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[IBAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) (International Bank Account Number) is the system used by bog-standard banks for transferring between accounts.

Ethereum has [ICAP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/master/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol.md) (Inter-exchange Client Address Protocol), which is effectively a decentralised version of IBAN.

From the [glossary](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/glossary.rst) in the Homestead guide:

> ICAP Interexchange Client Address Protocol, an IBAN-compatible system
>   for referencing and transacting to client accounts aimed to streamline
>   the process of transferring funds, worry-free between exchanges and,
>   ultimately, making KYC and AML concerns a thing of the past.

There's some further information under *Your First Account* in [this](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/blob/650c2f023c2e7184ca4ed84d50f263d84a6450fd/doc/gitbook/getting_started.md#your-first-account) guide.

Comment: But aren't these requirements already met by Ethereum public addresses?

Comment: @Sebi, nope, [see this brilliant thread](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/267/87).

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't spot the duplicate!