# Jaxx Wallet QR Code shows IBAN and etherscan shows 0 balance

Tags: etherscan, jaxx, qrcode

When I scan the QR code from the Jaxx Etherium wallet I get

```
iban:XE482ECP16CJCBQHZ7S844BEK8K1SDOX0HH
```

but it shows my address as

```
0x1488e397bc44c56d801a6e96217554a0e310ecb5
```

in the app it shows I have 0.59755900 ETH

but on etherscan that address has 0 ETH

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1488e397bc44c56d801a6e96217554a0e310ecb5

My questions are, why doesn't the QR code scan to my address and secondly why does etherscan.io show my balance as 0 when jaxx says I have 0.59755900 ETH??

[image: Jaxx Screenshot]

Comment: I found the ether is actually in this account, but why does Jaxx show me its in another account? https://etherscan.io/address/0x60c17817146f2b88f9cb414a49382d7a60d0ada4

Comment: how did you found this address?

Comment: Same EXACT issue.  When I scan the QR code with Coinbase's mobile app (simulating a customer paying me with ETH), I get the "iban" weird address, rather than the actual correct ETH address.  What gives here??  Sending to the QR Code from MyEtherWallet instead works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jaxx offers something called an  HD or Hierarchical Deterministic wallet which uses your initial seed to generate new addresses each time you make a transaction. This is designed to increase privacy and was inspired by Bitcoin but creates a few usability quirks with the Ethereum account model and also tokens in Jaxx.

Either way you can always see your exact balance and which address it is sitting on by heading to your Tools section and clicking to Display Your Ethereum Keys. This view will show you all of your Ethereum addresses and the individual balances they hold. Incidentally you can also use these private keys to export the address to another wallet if required.

In regards to the IBAN this is a separate way that some wallets use to send funds and is designed to encourage adoption of Ethereum as a payment channel with the international code of XE as a prefix. Although it isn't widely in use right now, this would theoretically allow the Ethereum IBAN address to interact with the traditional banking system. You can read more about that here:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/331/1949